# TextView won't scroll

Tags: java, android, scroll

I am currently working in an android activity where I need a scroll-able dynamic text view. I am constantly adding new lines to this view, but as I add lines, to it, it will only go up to 4 lines (The number I set it too) then it won't scroll. This is my xml and relevant java code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Did you try to put your TextView in a ScrollView?

Answer (score 3):

It won't scroll unless you put it in a scroll view. And if you specify the `maxLines` it wont exceed that. So instead, don't specify max lines and add a height to your scroll view.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"> //or whatever height

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Ok I have tried this and I see the scroll bar showing up once the text gets long enough, but it still won't scroll on the screen.

Comment: And remove that line from your java `tv3.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` I have no idea what that does, but its not needed to scroll

Comment: Ok, Still having the same problem even with these changes. The last line is cut off a little so I know it's there but there's still no scroll funcationality

Comment: Did you remove `maxLines`?

Comment: Yes this is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

     </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply put it inside a scrollView and then set the height of the scrollView to `android:height="wrap_content"`.